# Mock interface as argument in phpUnit

Tags: phpunit, integration-testing, zend-framework3

I have the following code, while testing zend application using phpUnit:

Tested method:

```
public function save(AbstractEntity $row, $request = null)
{
    if ($row->getDef()) {
        $this->getRepository()->clearDef();
    }
    $this->getRepository()->save($row);
}
```

So I mocked Service itself and try to test call:

```
public function testEditActionPostFormValid()
{
    $this->mockService();
    $this->mockForm();
    $this->dispatch('/reference/metal/edit/1', 'POST');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(302);
    $this->assertRedirectTo('/reference/metal');
    $this->assertActionName('edit');
    $this->assertStandardParameters();
}
```

Form mocking:

```
 private function mockForm($isValid = true)
    {
        $mockCategoryForm = $this->getMockBuilder(MetalForm::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $mockCategoryForm->expects($this->any())->method('isValid')->willReturn($isValid);

        $this->overrideService(MetalForm::class, $mockCategoryForm);
    }
```

Service mocking:

```
    private function mockService($findAllReturn = [])
    {
        $mockEntity = new Metal();
        $mockEntity->setName('testName');

        $mockService = $this->getMockBuilder(MetalService::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $mockService->expects($this->any())->method('find')->willReturn($mockEntity);
        $mockService->expects($this->any())->method('findAll')->willReturn($findAllReturn);

        $this->overrideService(MetalService::class, $mockService);
    }
```

**But I get the following error:**

Failed asserting response code "302", actual status code is "500"

**Exceptions raised:**

```
Exception 'TypeError' with message 'Argument 1 passed to Mock_MetalService_66253896::save() must implement interface Core\Entity\AbstractEntity, null given, called in /opt/project/module/Reference/src/Controller/PlainReferenceController.php on line 51' in /opt/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php(646) : eval()'d code:35
```

If I delete interface as the first argument test will path well. How to mock **AbstractEntity** interface here?

Comment: It is had to say what is wrong because we do not know what your code is doing

Comment: Apparently, it tests the "save" method. What else you need to know. The question is how to mock interface for the first argument and not about what code is doing. What else info do you need to know to answer?

Comment: This questions misses code; cannot be answered. `delete interface as the first argument` there is no interface in your question. Raised Exception mentions an interace not being present on object `Metal`, you might want to start there, your likely missing `implements AbstractEntity` on your `class Metal`. Next to that, pure and only assumptions may be done unless you update (provide complete) code (and remove code irrelevant to the question). Also, you should use strict typing (e.g. public `function save(AbstractEntity $row, $request = null): void` to indicate no return value)